# How do I use json.net in my class after installing it with NuGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, nuget

I installed json.net using the NuGet package manager:

[image]

But now when I actually try to use the thing by doing something like:

```
JObject message = Jobject.parse(someJson);
```

I am getting `Type or namespace name 'JObject' could not be found`.

How do I include it in my solution after NuGet installation?

Comment: nuget adds the dll to your project references.  Jobject is not in your current namespace so you need to write out Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject or add the using statement as Thomas suggested.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to import the namespace containing the `JObject` class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Comment: Just an extra tip.  You can right click "JObject" and look for "Resolve".  It will add the namespace...if it is able to be found.

Comment: @granadaCoder, you can also press `Ctrl + .` on `JObject` to invoke the smart menu

Comment: Not sure why this isn't in their getting started guide